# The library 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

The imports I am using:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';
import 'package:imagetotext/homePage.dart';
```

However, the linter is giving me the following warning:

```
The library 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart'' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library. Try migrating the imported library. import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe
```

The dependencies I am using:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  splashscreen: ^1.3.3
```

[image: error image]

[image: problem]

Comment: This isn't a problem in your code, it's an issue caused by your project being null-safe and importing an older not-null-safe library. You've got a few options, you can: check for an updated version (possibly pre-release or beta) of splashscreen that supports null-safety; stop using the splashscreen library; migrate splashscreen to null-safety yourself and open a PR; wait for the author to update the library.

Answer (score 5):

Your project cannot opt in to null-safety because one of its dependent packages (`splashscreen`) has not been migrated to null-safety yet.

https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

> When all of an app’s direct dependencies support null safety, you can *run the app* with sound null safety.

You can either

- Ignore the warning and keep using the package at your own risk. You can disable the warning using:

  ```dart
  // ignore: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe
  ```
- Downgrade your app or each file's Dart SDK version (to 2.11 or older).
- Do not use the unmigrated package and remove from dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

you can ignore this with :

```
// ignore: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe
```